# How can I use Python and Selenium to comment on Instagram posts?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an Instagram robot class that takes the username and password and logs in to the account.
I wrote a comment function in this class to put the comment below the post, I use this function but when it opens a custom post, when I leave a comment I get an error.
I do not know the reason for this error
Please let me know if anyone knows a solution

my code:

```
from selenium import  webdriver
import time
import random


class InstaBot:
    #Create a contractor to open the browser and get the username and password of your Instagram account
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.username = username
        self.password = password


        #This function is used to login to your Instagram account
    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        #Open the browser and open the Instagram site
        driver.get('https://www.instagram.com')
        #Find the username box address via XPath
        user_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
        #Find the password box address via XPath
        password_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input')
        #Find the login button via Xpath
        button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]')
        #Click on the username box
        user_box.click()
        #And enter the username in the username box
        user_box.send_keys(self.username)
        time.sleep(5)
        #Click on the password box
        password_box.click()
        #And enter the password in the password box
        password_box.send_keys(self.password)
        time.sleep(5)
        #Finally, click the Login button
        button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        #Go to the home page by adding a username to continue the Instagram link
        acount = driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/%s/'%(self.username))

    def comment(self,message=None):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/CLP-HN9AP0i/')
        coment_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/section[3]/div/form/textarea').click()
        coment_box.send_keys(message)

mobin = InstaBot('your user name','your password')
mobin.login()
time.sleep(5)
mobin.comment('Very Good')
```

The error it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mobin\Desktop\test_projcet.py", line 50, in <module>
    mobin.comment('Very Good')
  File "C:\Users\Mobin\Desktop\test_projcet.py", line 45, in comment
    coment_box.send_keys(message)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

The problem it you are setting your comment_box equal to an driver action not a web element. It will send out error "object has no attribute 'send_keys'" because it not an web element.

Also your comment_box is load more than one time. So you need to declare comment_box again after clicking it the first time.

### Solution

remove click at the end of this line

```
coment_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('your xpath').click()
```

replace with this code, it should work:

```
coment_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('your xpath')
coment_box.click()
time.sleep(5)
coment_box_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('your xpath')
coment_box.send_keys(message)
```

Comment: Your solution is Correct

Comment: add some implicity wait time or exlicit wait time to make sure driver actually wait for element. Add this code: self.driver.implicitly_wait(20) in your init.